# why R Shiny Loading Spinner from shinycssloaders is not showing up

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to add a Loading Spinner on my table output. But the Spinner disappeared when I ues the column name of the table to update the choices of a checkboxGroupInput. Here is a example of the issue.

Is there any way to fix this or are there any other loading icon options?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)
data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = 'a', label = 'show dataset'),
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'b', label = 'Select Column'),
  tableOutput('table')%>% withSpinner(),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data = eventReactive(input$a, {
    # Pause for 3 seconds to simulate a long computation.
    Sys.sleep(3)
    mtcars
  })

  # loading spin disappear afer I add updateCheckboxGroupInput based on the output data column names 
  observeEvent(input$a, {updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'b', choices = colnames(data()))})

  # if updateCheckboxGroupInput does not depend on output data, loading spin will show up
  #observeEvent(input$a, {updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'b', choices = c('a','b','c'))})

  output$table = renderTable({data()})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma on this line:
`tableOutput('table')%>% withSpinner(),`

Just incase anyone else looks at this, the example is also using pipes, i.e. `%>%`, but no package that adds them. You can switch to `withSpinner(tableOutput('table'))` or include `library(magrittr)`